# Regex not matching correct string

Tags: sql, regex, netezza

I am busy building a lookup table for specific names of merchants. I tried to make use of the following regex but it's returning less results than the standard "like" function in Netezza SQL. Please refer to below:

**SQL Like function**: where trim(upper(a.MRCH_NME)) like '%CNA %' -- returns 4622 matches

**Regex function in Netezza SQL**: where array_combine(regexp_extract_all(trim(upper(a.MRCH_NME)),'.*CNA\s','i'),'|') = 'CNA' -- returns 2226 matches

I looked at the two result sets and found that strings such as the following aren't matched:

```
!C CNA INT ARR
*CNA PLATZ 0400
015764 CNA CRAD
C#CNA PARK 0
```

I made use of the following regex expression: **/.*CNA\s'/**

Any idea why the above strings aren't being returned as matches?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you need `\\s` or `[[:space:]]`. Also note that `\s` matches more than just space.

Comment: Acc. to [this reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzregexp_like.htm), `\s` matches *a white space character. White space is defined as `[\t\n\f\r\p{Z}]`.*. So, you  may only compare with `'.*CNA '` with `'i'`/  `'(?i).*CNA '`

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the quick response. Will try it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me the problem is more with your code rather than the regex. Look: `like '%CNA %'` returns all entries that *contain* a `CNA` substring followed with a literal space anywhere inside the entry. The `'.*CNA\s'` regex matches any 0+ chars other than newline followed with `CNA` and **any whitespace char*.

Acc. to [this reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzregexp_like.htm), `\s` matches *"a white space character. White space is defined as `[\t\n\f\r\p{Z}]`*.

Thus, you should in fact just use

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(MRCH_NME, 'CNA ', 'i')
```

or, better with a word boundary check:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(MRCH_NME, '\bCNA\b', 'i')
```

where `\b` marks a transition from a word to non-word and non-word to word character, thus ensuring a whole word search and justifying the regex usage.

If you do not need to match the merchant name as a whole word, use the regular `LIKE` with `'%CNA %'`, it should be more efficient.

Comment: Thank you kindly for the revised answer and explanation. I truly appreciate the help and patience with the question. I don't understand is the '\bCNA\b' syntax: Let's say the merchant name has multiple words such as "Mc Donalds" will the expression '\bMc\bDonalds\b' or '\bMc Donalds\b' as the \b indicates a word boundary correct? I to create an expression that is as generic as possible

Comment: @Atlas_Apple I advise to study [`\b` word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) reference. It does not consume the text, it only asserts a certain location inside the string. `'\bMc\bDonalds\b'` will never match any string, because there is no word boundary between `c` and `D` as both chars are letters, i.e. word chars. If you want to search for a whole word `Mc Donalds`, you will use `\bMc Donalds\b`. And if you need to match anything within non-word chars, you would use `(?<!\w)my search phrase(?!\w)`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should be using `regexp_like`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(MRCH_NME, 'CNA[ ]', 'i');
```

This would be logically identical to the following query using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE MRCH_NME LIKE '%CNA ';
```

Comment: Thank you, I replaced the function but I'm not getting any matches now. Should I consider using a different regex?

Comment: I made use of the following function and it worked: regexp_like(trim(upper(a.MRCH_NME)),'.*CNA\s'). I'll try the new one you posted as well. Really apprecaite the quick response and help Tim

Comment: Oh...yes I changed my answer to make the regex case insensitive.

Comment: There is no point using `.*` here, `REGEXP_LIKE` can find partial matches, too. So, `WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(MRCH_NME, 'CNA ', 'i');` is enough. Unless `CNA` should just be a whole word, then `WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(MRCH_NME, '\\bCNA\\b', 'i');` can be used (I assume Netezza regex is ICU powered).

Comment: Hi Wiktor. Thank you for the response. CNA is the merchant's name. What my end goal is, is to build a regex that can extract the specific merchant in question from a table of millions of different merchants and remove all the noise in terms of merchants that contain for instance CNA somewhere in the larger name. WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(MRCH_NME, '\\bCNA\\b', 'i'); Would this expression be interchangable for different merchant by just changing the CNA in this part '\\bCNA\\b' ?

Comment: @Atlas_Apple You may use anything within `\b`s provided the first and last chars of the merchant's name are letters or digits or `_`, and that guarantees *whole word* matching.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew fantastic! This really helps a lot. I really appreciate the assist

Comment: @WiktorStribi just a quick question: Is there a reason why Netezza returns no results using '\\bCNA\\b' but returns the exact amount when it is written as '\bCNA\b' ? does it not pick up the escaped \b when \\ is used?

Comment: @Atlas_Apple I posted another answer below with all my findings.